# concatenating 2 UMats to a 3rd

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I am just starting to use OpenCV 3.4 T-API UMats.  When using Mat previously I had a line of code that concatenated 2 Mats to a 3rd like this:

> mTmpCombined = mImageHighHue + mImageLowHue;

The VS2017 compiler will not let me do this with UMat as in:

> umTmpCombined = umImageHighHue + umImageLowHue;

Is there a way to do this with UMat?  For now, as a temporary workaround, I copy the individual UMats to Mats, do the 3 = 1 + 2 line and then copy that mtempCombined back to umTempCombined.  Seems like a lot of processing just to get this done.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Ed

Comment: `+` doesn't concatenate, it *adds* element-wise. are you sure you meant "concatenation"? to achieve addition, look for `scaleAdd` with `alpha` being 1.

Comment: Your right.  I don't know why concatenate came to the top of my head.  Hopefully the code was more obvious.  Hopefully someone will know if it can be done in OCV 3.4 -- Thanks

Comment: I said `scaleAdd`. that applies to v3.4 as well. if you have any problem, present it.

Comment: Jeeeze,  I can't read for s&%t.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I got so flustered with the fact that I used the word "concatenate" when it should have been a simple "add" I must have stopped reading before I got to the end. And I complain about my users doing this....  Thanks for the scaleAdd.  I will give that a try today.

Comment: It looks like a simple cv::add does the trick without the need for the scale parameter in scaleAdd.  "add" seems obvious once you see it but I never knew to look.  Thanks again.